# Hibernate / JPA difference in position of @JoinColumn in parent or child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

Was just trying to understand if there is a difference in functionality when placement of @joinColumn for JPA is in parent class vs when in child class

Assuming the address table has a column ident_employee and foreign key constraint

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "employee")  
public class Employee {
        
      @Id
      @Column("ident_employee")
      private long id;

      @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "ident_employee", referencedColumnName = "ident_employee")
      private Address address;
    
    }

@Entity
@TableName("address")
public class Address{
    
    @Id
    @Column("ident_address")
    private lond id;
    
    @Columnn("address")
    private String street;
    
}
```

Vs

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "employee")  
public class Employee {

      @Id
      @Column("ident_employee")
      private long id;

      @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private Address address;
    
}

@Entity
@TableName("address")
public class Address{
    
    @Id
    @Column("ident_address")
    private lond id;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "ident_employee")
    private Employee employee
    
    @Columnn("address")
    private String street;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put it on `OneToMany` you get a uni-directional relationship.

In the second case, you missed the `mappedBy` attribute in the `OneToMany` annotation, and there you get, in fact, TWO relationships.
The `OneToMany` will be mapped to a separate relationship table.

If you'd use the `mappedBy` attribute, you will have a bi-directional relationship.